# Passing data from one activity to another and then printing

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-intent

The problem I am having is that it prints out Null on the second activity and not the actual username that is entered. Is the data being passed to the second activity correctly? Does the second activity need more code? Sorry but not the best at programming.

I have this code in my main class

```
if (username.getText().toString().equals("batman") &&
password.getText().toString().equals("Joker")) { 
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Username and 
password is correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.*******.loginpage.User");
intent.putExtra("username",String.valueOf(username));
startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, User.class));
```

This is the code inside my second class.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user);

Intent intent = getIntent();
String username = getIntent().getStringExtra("username");

TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
textView.setText("Welcome" + " " + username );
```

Comment: It is because you were using new intent while you try to startActivity. 
Using your original intent will solve the problem.

Comment: In your second class you have `Intent intent = getIntent();
String username = getIntent().getStringExtra("username");`. You don't need `Intent intent = getIntent();` because you are not using it! This code 
`String username = getIntent().getStringExtra("username");`  will work just fine on its own.

Comment: Thanks, got it to work now after switching from String.valueOf to getText().toString()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is your intent in your first class

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.*******.loginpage.User"); <-- have created an intent
intent.putExtra("username",String.valueOf(username));
startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, User.class)); <-- but using new Intent
```

You have created an intent but you passing new intent. Use your created Intent instead of passing new Intent.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, User.class);
intent.putExtra("username",String.valueOf(username));
startActivity(intent);
```

**EDIT**

Instead using `String.valueOf(username)` you must use `username.getText()`, because `String.valueOf(username)` is method to translate your object to String.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, User.class);
intent.putExtra("username",username.getText());
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I put that new code in and now when I run and switch to the next activity, it is not printing the username. Should I be printing a different way? The activity has a text view and that is where I want the username to be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Two problems here.
First one is that you have to pass the intent where you put your extra instead of creating new one to startActivity, like

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, User.class);
intent.putExtra("username",username.getText().toString());
startActivity(intent);
```

Second problem is that username looks like editText, String.valueOf won't pass actual value, use username.getText().toString() like i mentioned in code.